# Is there way to automatically convert ant's build.xml to build.gradle

Tags: gradle, ant, build.gradle

Is there way to automatically convert ant's build.xml to build.gradle. I know we can include ant file in gradle file itself using : `ant.importBuild 'build.xml'`

But i do not want that. I have to create gradle build script & remove the ant build script. Is there any way, we can convert ant build to gradle build script ?

Answer (score 0):

No, currently Gradle only provides support for converting Maven to Gradle.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

However, Gradle does provide documentation how to migrate from Ant to Gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_ant.html